# Evaluate the integral $\int_{1}^{4} w/(w-3) dw$ if possible

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

Evaluate the following integral, if possible: 
$$\int_{1}^{4} \frac{w}{w-3} dw.$$ 
I am supposed to be using improper integrals so I know I should find
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow3^-} \int_{1}^{t} \frac{w}{w-3} dw + \lim_{t \rightarrow 3^+} \int_{t}^{4} \frac{w}{w-3} dw
$$
because $w$ can't equal $3$. Next, I need to solve for the integral, which for some reason I can't think of how to do AT ALL. Can someone please help?

Comment: `w can't equal 3`?? How come?

Comment: @Berci sorry i wrote down the wrong problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Notice that $\frac{w}{w-3} = \frac{w - 3 + 3}{w-3} = 1 +\frac{3}{w-3}$ and $lim_{t \to 3^{-}} ln |t - 3| = -\infty$

$\hskip1.3in$[image]

Comment: when its the limit t -> 3+ does it equal ∞

Comment: Never, try to draw the graph of $ln |t - 3|$. I'll graph it here, just a sec.

Comment: From both sides $ln |t -3|$ goes to $-\infty$

Comment: okay so it also = -∞ . does that mean i have to use L'Hospital to get an answer? sorry im super lost where to go with this problem

Comment: The answer is the integral does not converge. As you've already showed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** introduce variable $u:=w-2$ to reduce the problem to that of $\int_0^t\frac1x\,dx$.